# Find an exported symbol for ELF files

Tags: android, elf

Using Ghidra, I can see an exported symbol `com_android_internal_os_Zygote_nativeForkAndSpecialize` inside `libandroid_runtime.so` and I want to find that symbol using other tools such as `nm`, `objdump` and `readelf` as I wanted to get details such as the address offset etc.

I have tried `nm --demangle --dynamic`, `objdump -TC` and also `readelf -Ws` but I could not find the symbol in those output.

What should be the correct command to use?

**EDIT**

I think the mangled name is `_ZN7androidL54com_android_internal_os_Zygote_nativeForkAndSpecializeEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassiiP10_jintArrayiP13_jobjectArrayiP8_jstringS9_S5_S5_hS9_S9_hS7_S7_hh`

I grep the output from the tools for the string `grep -i nativefork`